# How to skip files that have no data in them in folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder, with 1000s of txt files. My code is working perfectly fine if there is data in the file.

Is there anyway to build logic in my code to check if the file is empty, and if empty to skip to the next one?

```
import glob

import os


path = 'path/to/file'


for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
  with open(filename, 'r',encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
    print(filename)
    text = f.read()
    do other stuff
```

Comment: `if f.readlines()==[]: continue`

Comment: Or more efficiently, `if not f.read(1): continue`

Comment: Probably helps to clarify that the boolean of an empty list is `False`

Comment: @zondo where do your lines go? I put them below the f.read() and the code stops after printing file name

Comment: Well, this is a string, but yes: still valid.

Comment: @rahlf23 where do your lines go? I put them below the f.read() and the code stops after printing file name

Comment: @RustyShackleford: It would go before the `f.read()`, although as long as you have that there anyway, it would be better just to put `if not text: continue` right after that line.

Comment: If you're reading the file contents anyway, you can skip the file if the contents are the empty string: `if not text: continue`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it worked. Kevin had it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to continue to the next file if its text is empty? Easy enough:

```
if not text: continue
```